# Plot Close of specific bar time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to plot yesterday's last bar close on the chart **WHEN** a new day begins.

I can not use `request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1], lookahead=enter code herebarmerge.lookahead_on)` because it returns the settlement, not the last candle close.

I also tried this:

```
var float last_close = na
closing_time = (hour == 18) and (minute == 30)
last_close := closing_time ? close : last_close    // Get the new close if it is 18:30, keep the old value otherwise
```

I would like to plot this close only when the new day begins, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `ta.change(time("D"))` will return `true` on the first bar of the day. You can use it to get previous bar `close` on each new day:

```
var float yestrdayClose = na

if ta.change(time("D"))
    yestrdayClose := close[1]
```